# PMSM - Motor values for a simulation

Tags: motor, inverter, brushless-dc-motor, drone, pmsm

I have a simulation of a PMSM using a ElectroCraft RPX22-042V24 Motor. For some testing purposes I need to increase the rpm by a lot. I am thinking about 30-40 000 rpm. Of course I searched for a corresponding motor but I didn't find any. Or at least none with a datasheet. Almost any drone Motor would fit but I was not able to find a datasheet. So I am wonding if anybody has a motor spec that I can use?
I have a 24 V supply and the constant load torque is 30 mNm (with <100 mNm peak).

Its not really a scientific approach but I tried to guess values. If the speed is high I assume that a lower frequency would be better so I chose 2 pole pairs. A low Lq/Ld inductance of 0.1 mH and a low resistance of 100 mOhm combined with a high flux of 50 mWb. Of course that didn't work, so I am really looking forward to your suggestions.

Why is it so hard to find a datasheet for a motor?